# XML parsing document.CreateElement exception Blackberry

Tags: xml, blackberry, java-me

I'm trying to do an xml parser in Blackberry. But i get a strange problem.

```
import org.w3c.dom.DOMException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import net.rim.device.api.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import net.rim.device.api.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

public class HelloWorld extends UiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld theApp = new HelloWorld();
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public HelloWorld() {
        pushScreen(new HelloWorldScreen());
    }
}

final class HelloWorldScreen extends MainScreen {


    public HelloWorldScreen() {    
        super();        
        LabelField title = new LabelField("XML TEST", LabelField.ELLIPSIS
                | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        setTitle(title);
        RichTextField rcfield = new RichTextField("XML TEST!");
        add(rcfield);
        this.doPaint();
        this.invalidate();
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db=null;
        Document doc = null;

        try {
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();          
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        doc = db.newDocument();         
        try{            
        Element e = doc.createElement("s:Envelop");
        }catch(DOMException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }



    }

    public boolean onClose() {
        Dialog.alert("Goodbye!");
        System.exit(0);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The error message:

```
[0.0] DOMException
[0.0] No detail message
[0.0] net_rim_xml(4C48DD8C)
[0.0]  DOMInternalRepresentation
[0.0]  isNCName
[0.0]  0x3930
[0.0] net_rim_xml(4C48DD8C)
[0.0]  DOMDocumentImpl
[0.0]  createElement
[0.0]  0x4CC
[0.0] VM:+CR
[0.0] VM:-CR=7
```

Error code5 : INVALID CHARACTER ERROR
Maybe the ":" is invalid character? But it works fine on android :/
I dont have any idea how to solve it :(

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671523/ksoap-parsing-query/7683966#7683966

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I want to creat a doc from string(i 've got a node type i can get their childs etc.)
So i just want to creat an element form a string.:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a namespaced element, but you have not defined the "s" prefix or its namespace URI before trying to use them.  Use `Document.createElementNS()` to create a namespaced element instead of `Document.createElement()`.

Alternatively, try calling `DocumentBuilderFactory.setAllowUndefinedNamespaces(true)` before calling `newDocumentBuilder()`, or `DocumentBuilder.setAllowUndefinedNamespaces(true)` before calling `newDocument()`.